# How to find all elements in B that contain any element of A, where A and B are lists of combinations of different lengths?

Tags: python, list, subset

Suppose `A = [[0, 1], [1, 2]]`, which stores two 2-combinations from `{0, 1, 2, 3}`, and `B = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`, which stores all possible 3-combinations from `{0, 1, 2, 3}`.

How to find all elements in `B` that contain at least one of the 2-combinations from `A`?

My desired output is `C = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`, where `[0, 1, 2]` includes both `[0, 1]` and `[1, 2]`, `[0, 1, 3]` includes `[0, 1]`, and `[1, 2, 3]` includes `[1, 2]`.

Thanks! (It would be great if the answer code is efficient and fast, as I need to do this for `A` and `B` that are of large scale)

I tried the following codes:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

A = [[0, 1], [1, 2]]
B = []
Cdup = []
rows = range(4)
for combo in itertools.combinations(rows, 3):
    B.append(list(combo))

print(B)

for b in B:
    for a in A:
        if a.issubset(b):
            Cdup.append(b)

C = np.unique(Cdup)
```

But there is an error that says `list` object has no attribute `issubset`.

Comment: What code do you have yourself so far?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each inner list contains unique values? That is, no duplicate items like `[0, 1, 1]` are possible?

Comment: @976993 Right. There is no duplicate.

Comment: @9769953 I just includes the codes

Comment: @9769953 I tried to add np.array() to a and b and it didn't work either

Comment: "an error that says list object has no attribute 'issubset'": if you convert the inner lists to sets, this will work (the name "issubset" is a give away). Hence my question about duplicates: if there are no duplicates, you're easier (and likely quicker) off comparing sets than lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could scan each element `b` of `listB` and check if any element `a` of `listA` is a subset of `b`, in that case keep `b`.

Coding:

```
[b for b in listB if any(set(a).issubset(set(b)) for a in listA)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Upvoted because this is the best solution for sure. I was trying to do something like that but I was using the operator `in`, which I thought was the one used by the `issubset()` method, and it was not working (for obvious reasons). Thanks for that, @iGian.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `itertools.combinations`, comprehensions, and `set`:

```py
from itertools import combinations

A = [(0, 1), (1, 2)]
B = list(combinations(range(4), 3))
C = set(b for a in A for b in B if a in set(combinations(b, len(a))))

print(C)
```

Which results in:

```py
{(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (1, 2, 3)}
```

The solution above assumes that `len(a) <= len(b)` where `a` and `b` are elements of `A` and `B`, respectively. What it does is simply check if each element of `A` is an element of the combinations of each element of `B`, combined by the `len()` of elements of `A`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and explanation! This is very helpful. I further changing c from set to list will deliver what I want.

Comment: You can convert `c` to list AFTER the comprehension. `set` is needed to remove the duplicated combinations. Something like `c = list(set(...`  will do the job.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code can be a solution for your scenario, let me know if you think it needs any explanations:

```
listA=[[0,1],[1,2]]
listB=[[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,3],[1,2,3]]
res = []

for comA in listA:

    strA = " ".join(str(e) for e in comA)

    for comB in listB:
    
        strB = " ".join(str(el) for el in comB)
    
        if strA in strB:
        
            res.append(list(comB))
            # use tuple if you want to remove duplicates easily:
            # res.append(tuple(comB))


print(res)

# if the res list contain tuples the to remove duplicates we can use:
# mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(res))
# print(mylist)
```

Comment: Beware: with `listA = [[0, 2], [0, 3]]`, your current code would miss `[0, 1, 2]` and `[0, 1, 3]`. Maybe sets would be more appropriate than strings...

Comment: @HosseinKoofi Thanks. This is helpful. I guess it needs an additional step: dropping duplicates from res.

Comment: @T34driver by having tuples inside res instead of lists ==> res.append(tuple(comB))  then in the global section you can easily delete the duplicates by ===> mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(res))

Comment: @HosseinKoofi I see. Thanks!